# Flutter - how to add done button in number keyboard in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to add `done` button in number type input for a `TextFormField` in flutter but I could not able to do that.

```
TextFormField(
          key: Key(keyValue),
          initialValue: valueBuilder,
          onSaved: (text) {
            fieldsController.text = text.trim();
          },
          inputFormatters: [inputFormatters],
          keyboardType: TextInputType.phoneNumber,)
```

I want create a keyboard like the below. For the input text form field.

[image: this]

Comment: Have you tried setting the `TextInputAction` on your form field?  https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/TextInputAction-class.html

Comment: keyboardType: TextInputType.number,   
textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,

Comment: Yes but that is also not working in IOS platform since mac OS does not support such UI in number keyboard,so looking for a solution

Comment: i am using textform field ,which is manily to easily do with the validation part of the field ,so replacing with cupertinoTextField will make my validation work harder

Comment: 4 years and still no native solution

Answer (score 54):

Change

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.number
```

to

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true)
```

Comment: I think this is a good **temporary** workaround for a **built-in done button** on a **numeric keyboard** for **iOS**.

Comment: You only need `signed: true` to trigger this workaround.

Comment: with this solution there will be numbers and other characters on the keyboard, not just numbers

Comment: @GiulioPretis Characters are shown but not clickable...so, it allows only Numbers & that is what required in this case. you can set **decimal** to **false** here if you want to use All characters from Standard Keyboard.

Comment: I don't know what other people are getting but with this option it shows the FULL keyboard, not the small numeric keyboard. It's not any kind of solution at all.

Answer (score 21):

You don't need a `done` button just wrap `MaterialApp` with a `GestureDetector`

```
GestureDetector(
  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
  onTap: () {
    FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

    if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus &&
        currentFocus.focusedChild != null) {
      FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus.unfocus();
    }
  },
  child: MaterialApp(
     title: "My title",
     home:MyHomeScreen(),
     ),
);
```

Comment: The method 'unfocus' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  - i got this error

Comment: That's the way to go! Thanks a lot. But I want to add one more thing. I think behavior should be set as HitTestBehavior.translucent

Comment: Depending on your flutter version. If ```HitTestBehavior.translucent``` works for you then it's fine. I hope you're not doing that because you saw the warning on your console.
this worked perfectly on ```flutter 1.2```

Comment: This will make the app pretty janky, best to use this sparingly around root view widgets.

Comment: Not a great solution since not everyone will know to even do that. They'll just be sat there looking at a keyboard that looks un-closable. Good way to get a quick 1 star review for your app.

Answer (score 20):

I've just created a package for add basic actions to the current keyboards .

[image]

You can take a look here :

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/keyboard_actions

Usage :

```
    import  'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import  'package:keyboard_actions/keyboard_actions.dart';

     //...
      FocusNode _nodeText1 = FocusNode();
      FocusNode _nodeText2 = FocusNode();
      FocusNode _nodeText3 = FocusNode();
      FocusNode _nodeText4 = FocusNode();
      FocusNode _nodeText5 = FocusNode();

     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Keyboard Actions Sample"),
          ),
          body: FormKeyboardActions(
            keyboardActionsPlatform: KeyboardActionsPlatform.ALL, //optional
            keyboardBarColor: Colors.grey[200], //optional
            nextFocus: true, //optional
            actions: [
              KeyboardAction(
                focusNode: _nodeText1,
              ),
              KeyboardAction(
                focusNode: _nodeText2,
                closeWidget: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ),
              KeyboardAction(
                focusNode: _nodeText3,
                onTapAction: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          content: Text("Custom Action"),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                              child: Text("OK"),
                              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                            )
                          ],
                        );
                      });
                },
              ),
              KeyboardAction(
                focusNode: _nodeText4,
                displayCloseWidget: false,
              ),
              KeyboardAction(
                focusNode: _nodeText5,
                closeWidget: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Text("CLOSE"),
                ),
              ),
            ],
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      focusNode: _nodeText1,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Input Number",
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      focusNode: _nodeText2,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Input Text with Custom Close Widget",
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      focusNode: _nodeText3,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Input Number with Custom Action",
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                      focusNode: _nodeText4,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Input Text without Close Widget",
                      ),
                    ),
                    TextField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                      focusNode: _nodeText5,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: "Input Number with Custom Close Widget",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
```

Comment: There really isn't a whole lot of explanation on the pub page. Just a bunch of code. Flutter pros will be ok I guess, but the README is not very beginner friendly.

Comment: This package works well and is the only actual solution on this entire page. One problem is I find now when the keyboard opens it pushes the widgets of my app up a bit, whereas the ordinary keyboard with no done button did not. resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, does not prevent it from doing it either. Any idea how to remedy this?

Answer (score 16):

add this to your TextField

```
TextField(
...
keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true),
inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
],
...
),
```

Comment: This won't work for decimal values

Comment: What does inputFormatters do? I tried with and without it and got same result

Comment: Doesn't work. It shows the full QWERTY keyboard for me, it's not the numeric keyboard.

Answer (score 15):

This is how to add **Done** button to your `TextFormField` when keyboard is opened:

```
textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
```

Please keep in mind that iOS doesn’t support **Done** on `NUMERIC` keyboards.

Comment: The question is specifically how to add a `Done` button on a numeric keyboard

Answer (score 6):

I used this way to handle done button in IOS

```
      keyboardType: Platform.isIOS? 
                    TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed: true, decimal: true)
                  : TextInputType.number,
// This regex for only amount (price). you can create your own regex based on your requirement
     inputFormatters: [FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d+\.?\d{0,4}'))],
```

Comment: Great, how can modify the regex to accept as well + ?

Answer (score 3):

There is no done button in ios keyboard. Solution is that use "**keyboard_actions**" plugin otherwise add layout top of keyboard check this

**https://blog.usejournal.com/keyboard-done-button-ux-in-flutter-ios-app-3b29ad46bacc**

Answer (score 0):

I used the signed option to display the done button. Then I used a TextInputFormatter with a RegEx to limit what the user can input.

```
new TextFormField(
              controller: myController,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(signed:true, decimal: true),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              onFieldSubmitted: (term) {
                _showSnackBar(context, double.parse(myController.text));
              },
              onEditingComplete: () {
                _showSnackBar(context, double.parse(myController.text));
              },
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                helperText: "Actual",
                hintText: "Units used",
                border: UnderlineInputBorder(),
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard),
              ),
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\d*\.?\d*$')),
              ],
            ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a done button on the bottomSheet of Scaffold.

[image: Example]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
 }

 class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  bottomSheet: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0
      ? null
      : Row(
          children: [
            const Spacer(),
            TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus?.unfocus();
                },
                child: const Text("Done"))
          ],
        ),
  appBar: AppBar(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
    title: const Text("Keyboard done button"),
  ),
  body: ListView(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    keyboardDismissBehavior: ScrollViewKeyboardDismissBehavior.onDrag,
    children: [
      TextFormField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'Some text',
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]
You can make it easy with some simple code.

1. Keep setting for TextField with keyboardType is TextInputType.number
2. Define variable to detect keyboard state and set it in your state build

> isVisible = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom != 0;

3. Wrap your widget inside Stack, add this code at bottom

> ```
> Stack(
>       children: [
>         ... Your widget ...
>         if (isVisible)
>           Align(
>             alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
>             child: Padding(
>               padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
>               child: Container(
>                 color: Colors.white70,
>                 height: 40,
>                 child: GestureDetector(
>                   onTap: () {
>                     FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
>                   },
>                   child: const Padding(
>                     padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 4, 10, 4),
>                     child: Row(
>                       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
>                       children: [
>                         Text(
>                           'Xong',
>                           style: TextStyle(
>                               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
>                               fontSize: 15,
>                               color: Colors.blue
>                           ),
>                         )
>                       ],
>                     ),
>                   ),
>               ),
>             )
>           )
>         )
>       ],
>     )
> ```

Answer (score -3):

There is no `done` button in `iOS` but we can check the length of the input and clear `focus` to hide the numberpad keyboard. 
Implement like below,(it'll work with fix length of number value)

```
onChanged: (val) {
        if (val.length == 10) { //10 is the length of the phone number you're allowing
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        }
      }
```