# how do I know when a Keyboard key is pressed on TextFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I know when the done key is pressed on the TextFormField, and clear what is written and save what is written in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the part to clear values of TextFormField you can do the following according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57747739/13444299):

```
String selectedValue;
List selectedValueList;
 var _controller = TextEditingController();
    List selectedValuesList;
    String selectedValue;
          TextFormField(
            controller: _controller,
            labelText: "Enter value"),
            onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                       selectedValue = value;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

and whenever you want to clear it you can call the folowing

```
    controller.clear(),
```

for the done key I don't know exactly what you're after but you can check something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53505500/flutter-how-to-add-done-button-in-number-keyboard-in-flutter) if it can help you to get to what you want,
and by the time that that done key is pressed you do the following:

```
selectedValueList.add(selectedValue);
selectedValue="";
_controller.clear(),
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with `onsubmitted:` function in text field
this function will call when user submits the text ,
you can also control the action with `textInputAction`
like below

```
textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
```